# Send API data and image but always empty

Tags: html, ajax, api, slim

I'm trying to send a user picture to my api with Slim 3, PHP 7 and JQuery 2.1.1
But when I call api in HTML page then I get couple errors in Apache log, it seems that data arguments are empty and I dont know why.
Someone could help?

```
-------HTML source code api call
function savePicture(){
      
  var fID = $('#edtIDUser').val();
  var fPicture = document.getElementById('img').src;
         
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url:"index.php/user_picture/",
    timeout:3000,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",        
    data:{'id_user': fID, 'picture': fPicture},
    dataType:"text",
    async:false,
    error: function (request, error) {          
      alert("error");
    },
    success: function (result) {
      alert("ok");
    }
  });

}
```

AND API

```
----API source code 
    $app->post('/user_picture/',  function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    
    $params = $request->getParsedBody();
    
    $iduser = $params['id_user'];
    
    $uploadedFile = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $img = $uploadedFile['picture'];    

    $data               = file_get_contents($img);
    $escaped            = bin2hex($data);

    //TO-DO
}
```

Error #1: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in $params['id_user']
Error #2: Undefined index 'picture'
Error #3: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions of your HTML as well?

Comment: This looks suspicious to me: `index.php/user_picture/`. It should be `/user_picture`. Also the route should be `$app->post('/user_picture', ...`

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the ajax part of your code, you cannot upload a photo like that using the provided javascript above, the $request->getUploaddedFiles() will fetch the uploaded images using FormData, read the documentation for slim3 uploading file here http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/uploading-files.html